# What is the difference between local repository, remote respository and virtual repository in JFrog Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

Could someone please explain what's are these 3 types of repos local, remote and virtual in JFrog Artifactory. , I'm not getting a clear picture of it from JFrog Artifactory documentation.

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories

Answer (score 11):

- Local repositories are physical, locally-managed repositories into which you can deploy artifacts.
- A remote repository serves as a caching proxy for a repository managed at a remote URL (which may itself be another Artifactory remote repository).
  Artifacts are stored and updated in remote repositories according to various configuration parameters that control the caching and proxying behavior. You can remove artifacts from a remote repository cache but you cannot actually deploy a new artifact into a remote repository.
- A virtual repository (or "repository group") aggregates several repositories with the same package type under a common URL.

Comment: OP mentioned he/she didn´t get a clear picture from the documentation but the answer is basically copy -> paste from the documentation. I am not sure it really helped OP, just my opinion.

Comment: It says "Artifacts are stored and updated in remote repositories " but also "you cannot actually deploy a new artifact into a remote repository." I dont understand, can you deploy artifacts to a remote repository or not?

Comment: @TomE the artifacts get to the remote repository as they are proxied from the remote source. You can't deploy to remote repository directly, but the artifacts get there for sure.

Answer (score 4):

The way I see it is this (written from the point of view of Maven/Java/Intelli J user):

**Remote Repo:**

Think of the case of a large number of developers in the company pulling Artefacts from Maven central. It creates a lot of network traffic across the internet, or possibly you have policies restricting this. To solve this we create a remote repository in Artifactory that acts like a proxy and local cache for Maven central. Now Maven can pull Artefacts from your remote repo in Artifactory and Artifactory will pull them from Maven Central. This also gives Artifactory the ability to scan artefacts and potentially take action based on vulnerabilities.

**Local Repo:**

So you've downloaded a bunch of artefacts into your local project, built your own code and want to package it up and make it available to other people in the company. This is where the local repo comes in. It's a place to deploy your own artefacts.

**Virtual Repo:**

Think about someone else in the company wanting to use your Artefact in their project, but they also need stuff from Maven Central. They would need to pull from 2 repos. With a virtual repo you can effectively combine 2 or more repos into a single virtual repo. For the developer they just see the single repo but underneath it could be a local and remote repo. This would also be useful if you want to combine multiple remote repos, eg I've seen companies like Splunk and MapR have their own repos. Previously I would need to add these various repos into my POM file. Now I can just create a new remote repo in Artifactory and add that repo to my virtual repo.